# How to execute 'clean' task in the end of my custom task?

Tags: gradle

I've create my own simple task so I want to clean before test

```
task cleanTest (group: 'test setup', description: 'clean then test.'){
dependsOn 'clean'
dependsOn 'test'
tasks.findByName('test').mustRunAfter 'clean'
}
```

After my task is finished I want to run clean task

Iv'e tried

```
configure(subprojects) {
task clean << {
    println "Do clean " + project.name
}

task test(dependsOn: clean)<<{
    println 'test ' + project.name
}

task cleanTest(dependsOn: cleanTest)<<{
    parent.cleanTest.execute()
}
}
```

All I want is to run 'clean task in the end of my custom task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. You cannot run a task multiple times in one Gradle run. So if you want to do the same actions before and after your task, define a method that you run before and after the task. Using `Task.execute()` is **not** cleanly possible. Never ever do or even try this. It is a purely internal method that should never-ever-ever be called directly by any build ever. It is prone to produce strange and unpredictible results.

What you want is probably something around the lines of

```
subprojects {
    def cleanIt = {
        println "Do clean " + project.name
    }

    clean.doLast {
        cleanIt()
    }

    task test(dependsOn: clean) {
        doLast {
            println 'test ' + project.name
        }
    }

    task cleanTest(dependsOn: cleanTest) {
        doLast {
            cleanIt()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clean before test then simply make test depend on clean. That makes sure that before every test, clean is executed. This is how gradle does stuff.

```
task clean() {}
task test(dependsOn: clean) {}
```

There is also question how to run clean after mytask.. To run clean task after mytask you can use thirdtask depending on both and specify forced order between clean and mytask

```
task clean() {}
task mytask() {}
task thirdtask(dependsOn: [clean, mytask]){}
clean.mustRunAfter mytask
```

If the question was whether you can run clean task multiple times in a single build then that is not possible and see answer from Vampire to share the code.

Comment: Thank you, I was asking about whether I can run clean task multiple times in a single build, now I see that is impossible to run this way